# Pulling images from Github container registry is too slow in the last layer

Tags: docker, github, ghcr

Our team uses GitHub Container Registry to host our production docker images.
There's a step in our team's CI/CD where one of our GitHub workflows creates and hosts the image on `ghcr.io`.

Then the image needs to be pulled on our VPSs in order to be used for hosting our projects.

The problem is that the very last layer of each image is pulled way too slowly and the process takes forever (a 200 MB Layers takes at least 40 minutes...).

Is there any way to boost this pulling process from GitHub Container Register?

Comment: Does this layer contain more files than the other layers?

Comment: @A.L not necessarily, sometimes yeah but also sometimes no.